# Draw barchart groups with \pgfplotsinvokeforeach

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, pgffor

I'm using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to try to draw 2 series on a bar chart. This is a pre-requisite and I can't change this (since part of a bigger project).

However, since I'm using 1 single `addplot` command per bar, Tikz thinks there are 4 different series (2 orange before the tick, 2 purple after).

[image: MWE output]

How can I avoid this behavior ?

I'd like **only** 2 series, but drawn by 2 `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`...

Here is what I'm working on :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = Current Situation,
        axis on top,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line=none,
        ybar=.5cm,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        xtick={1,2}
        ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,2}{%
            \addplot[draw=orange, fill=orange] coordinates {(#1, #1)};
        }%
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,2}{%
            \addplot[draw=purple, fill=purple] coordinates {(#1, 2*#1)};
        }%
        
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title = Expected Behavior,
            axis on top,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line=none,
            ybar=.5cm,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            xtick={1,2}
            ]
            \addplot[draw=orange, fill=orange] coordinates {(1, 1) (2, 2)};
            \addplot[draw=purple, fill=purple] coordinates {(1, 2) (2, 4)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

To summarize the situation :

- I'd like 1 `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` per serie to draw (2 in my example)
- Each series understood as a serie by Tike, reproducing the layout of the second graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on automatic shift, you can set the `bar shift` explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = Current Situation,
        axis on top,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line=none,
        ybar=.5cm,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        xtick={1,2},
        ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,2}{%
            \addplot[draw=orange, fill=orange, bar shift=-12 pt] coordinates {(#1, #1)};
        }%
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,2}{%
            \addplot[draw=purple, fill=purple, bar shift=12 pt] coordinates {(#1, 2*#1)};
        }%
        
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title = Expected Behavior,
            axis on top,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line=none,
            ybar=.5cm,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            xtick={1,2}
            ]
            \addplot[draw=orange, fill=orange] coordinates {(1, 1) (2, 2)};
            \addplot[draw=purple, fill=purple] coordinates {(1, 2) (2, 4)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Two identical bar graphs]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks !